# Putting up delay in promises

Tags: javascript, promise, promise.all

So, I have two promises that I want to print on screen with a 3sec delay in between. How would I achieve it. Below is the code.

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Hello")
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Good Morning")
});

Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const response = Promise.all.next();
    console.log(response);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a delay function. First you loop through each response in the array and use the delay in between

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Hello")
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Good Morning")
});
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(async function(resps) {
     
   for(let res of resps){
   console.log(res);
    await delay(3000)
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, you just need to receive the value from the results of the `Promise.all` and then handle that information, like this:

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve("Hello")
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve) {
   resolve("Good Morning");
});

Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo])
    .then(function(response) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(response);
        }, 3000);
    });
```

---

**Edit**
According to the clarification given by OP what he needs is the following:

After the first promise is resolved, wait 3 seconds and then execute the second promise.

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve("Hello")
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve) {
   resolve("Good Morning");
});


async function resolveWithDelay(delay = 3000) {
    const res1 = await promiseOne;
    console.log(res1);

    setTimeout(async () => {
        const res2 = await promiseTwo;
        console.log(res2);
    }, delay);
}

resolveWithDelay();
```

Comment: will this put delay in between the two promises? Or do I switch it with setinterval?

Comment: @new2coding Both promises will be resolved immediately & `Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then()` will also invoke immediately. Just it will `console.log` after 3 seconds.

Comment: @Karan I want to add a delay in between these two promises.

Comment: @new2coding So I guess you want to `resolve` `promiseTwo` `3 seconds` after `promiseOne` resolves, right?

Comment: @new2coding That should do it, no matter how long the original promises take to resolve. As soon as both get resolved there's going to be a delay of 3 seconds and then something will be executed.

Comment: @Karan Yes. That is what i am after

Comment: Your edited code will also `resolved` `immediately` just it will print after 3 seconds. Try using `then` after `promiseOne` and `promiseTwo` you will understood it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("Hello")
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("Good Morning")
});

Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function(all) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(all);
        }
        , 3000);
    });

}).then(console.log)
```

Return new Promise in `then`, that promise waits for `x` millisecond and resolve it.

And do anything in next `then`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delay the log then you can add `response` parameter as explained by [@Daniel Rodríguez Meza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127040/9695286).

But if you want to delay `response` from any one of the promise `promiseOne` or `promiseTwo` then you should use `setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello"), 300);` inside respective promise as shown below. Also do not use `setTimeout` inside `Promise.All`.

As per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126998/putting-up-delay-in-promises/63127098#comment111629895_63127040) I have updated answer to `resolve` `promiseTwo` `3 seconds` after `promiseOne` resolves.

Here I've assigned `resolve` of `promiseTwo` to global variable `resolvePromiseTwo` which is used inside `promiseOne` to `resolve` `promiseTwo` after 3 seconds.

**Note** I have used `.then` after `promiseOne` and `promiseTwo` just to verify `output`. You can omit both.

```js
let resolvePromiseTwo = null;

const promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Good Morning")
  setTimeout(() => resolvePromiseTwo("Hello"), 3000);
}).then(res => {
  console.log('promiseOne resolved');
  return res;
});

const promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolvePromiseTwo = resolve;
}).then(res => {
  console.log('promiseTwo resolved');
  return res;
});

Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Promise.all');
  console.log(response);
});
```